# Read from Google Cloud Storage and Load to Google Data Store

Tags: google-cloud-storage, datastore

I am new to Google Cloud and exploring DataStore. I am not a programmer and wish to become one.

*Can anyone help me for the requirement below?*

**I have a JSON file which had around 5000 records and I would like to load the data to Google DataStore. If anyone can explain step by step process I will gladly implement it.**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you would like to use JSON to import into Datastore, you will need to use Dataflow

With [Cloud Storage Text to Datastore template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloud-storage-text-to-datastore) you can read from text files stored in Cloud Storage and write JSON encoded Entities to Datastore. Each line in the input file should be in JSON format specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/Entity)

#### If you had export something before, and you would like to export it back, you can follow this one (NOT JSON)

If you would like to import your data from a Google Cloud Storage Bucket to Google Datastore you will need to:

I saw that you mentioned that you have already a file in your Cloud Storage Bucket. If it was not the case, you can always refer to this [quickstart on how to create a Cloud Storage Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-console#create_a_bucket).

> It is very important to create or have already your Cloud Storage bucket **in the same location** as your Cloud Datastore.

To continue, make sure to assign an IAM role to your user account that grants the next permissions:

- `datastore.databases.import`. The `Datastore Import Export Admin` role, for example grants both permissions.
- You can also give the user who is gonna make the import `Editor` role, but I highly recommend you to divide the permissions since the beginning, as you will become used to not giving extra permissions to your users.

If you are not sure on how to add/grant or revoke different roles, you can take a look at this guide on how [Granting, changing, and revoking access to resources works](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access).

Finally, you have different options when it comes to imports and how you would like to do it. You can use the console, gcloud or rest, by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#importing_all_entities).

If you would like to continue working with Datastore, I highly recommend you to take a look at its [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices).

Comment: Thanks Christopher. On one of the link u provided i could see how to do batch operation on Data store, i wish to write a Java program for it however can u guide me how can i write this in Eclipse and invoke it in Google Cloud?  https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#batch_operations

Comment: For using Java with Datastore, I recommend you this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore) and also how to [create, retrieve, update and delete entities](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/creating-entities) using App Engine with Datastore. If you would like more flexibility you can always use the [Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) with Java.